# Install Telescope (Meteor.JS) Mannually

Tags: meteor, telescope

I decided to install Telescope App mannually using this guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx

At what point should I do `git clone https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope.git` ?
Also, might I encounter any problems due to installing on Ubuntu 16.04 and not 14.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point where it says "Then create an application...", and it should work just fine under 16.04.

But given that you had to ask ... I think you would be better off trying to learn one thing at at time, not mixing OS administration, deployment and Meteor learning at the same time...

Comment: So, instead of `meteor create --example todos` I should just do `git clone https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope.git`?

Comment: Yes. As you know, both commands will result in an application folder being created. I hope you also realize that from this point on you will have to adapt all the commands in the tutorial, since you are working with a different application than the one it is written for.